# Plane wave shift in a differential operator

Tags: operators, relativity

Does anyone can help me to prove the following equation
\begin{equation}
e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}f(\partial_{\mu})e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}} = f(\partial_{\mu}+ik_{\mu})
\end{equation}
Where $\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}=k^{\mu}x_{\mu}, \mu = 0,1,2,3$.

Comment: Assume that $f$ admits a Taylor expansion. This assumption is actually implicit here since we are taking the argument to be an operator. Perform the Taylor expansion, compute each term separately, and then resum.

Comment: Hint : I think that a first step would be to prove by induction that equation is valid for $f\left(z \right)=z^{n}$ that is $\:e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\partial_{\mu}^{n} e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}=\left( \partial_{\mu}+ik_{\mu}\right)^{n}$ and so for every polynomial with complex coefficients  $f\left(z \right)=\sum c_{m}z^{m}$, since the equation is linear with respect to $f$. Then use the Taylor expansion of Prahar's comment.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $g$ is a function in the space of rapidly decreasing functions with all their derivatives of any order, the so-called *Schwartz space* ${\cal S}(\mathbb R^4)$. 
Define $$\hat{g}(k) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2} \int_{\mathbb R^4} e^{-i k_\mu x^\mu} g(x) d^4x\::$$ As a consequence, as is well known, $\hat{g} \in {\cal S}(\mathbb R^4)$ and
$$g(x) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2} \int_{\mathbb R^4} e^{i k_\mu x^\mu} \hat{g}(k) d^4k\:.$$ 
Moreover, by standard results on the interchange of integration and derivative symbols which are valid on the class of functions we are dealing with, we find 
$$\partial^{n_1}_{1}\cdots \partial^{n_4}_{4} g(x) = 
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2} \int_{\mathbb R^4} \partial^{n_1}_{1}\cdots \partial^{n_4}_{4}e^{i k_\mu x^\mu} \hat{g}(k) d^4k$$
$$=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2} \int_{\mathbb R^4} (ik)^{n_1}_{1}\cdots (ik)^{n_4}_{4} e^{i k_\mu x^\mu} \hat{g}(k) d^4k\:.$$
and more generally assuming that the sum in the right-hand side encompasses a finite number of terms, where $a_{n_1\ldots n_4}$ are complex constants,
$$\sum_{n_1\ldots n_4}a_{n_1\ldots n_4}\partial^{n_1}_{1}\cdots \partial^{n_4}_{4} g(x) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2} \int_{\mathbb R^4} \sum_{n_1\ldots n_4}a_{n_1\ldots n_4}(ik)^{n_1}_{1}\cdots (ik)^{n_4}_{4} e^{i k_\mu x^\mu} \hat{g}(k) d^4k\:.$$
In other words, if $p=p(\partial_{1},\cdots, \partial_{4})$ is a **complex polynomial**, where I assume $$c\partial^0_\alpha := cI$$ in particular,
$$\left(p(\partial_{1},\cdots, \partial_{4}) g\right)(x) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2} \int_{\mathbb R^4} p(ik_1,\cdots, ik_4) e^{i k_\mu x^\mu} \hat{g}(k) d^4k\:.\tag{1}$$
There are several reasons to extend this identity to a class of functions $f$ larger than polynomials $p$, extending also the class of functions $g$ for instance to the space of *Schwartz distributions* if necessary. This is because the ring of polynomials if dense in larger spaces of functions with respect to relevant topologies.
This extension makes sense as soon as $p_n \to f$ implies 
$$\int_{\mathbb R^4} p_n(ik_1,\cdots, ik_4) e^{i k_\mu x^\mu} \hat{g}(k) d^4k \to 
\int_{\mathbb R^4} f(ik_1,\cdots, ik_4) e^{i k_\mu x^\mu} \hat{g}(k) d^4k\:.$$
If $$\int_{\mathbb R^4} f(ik_1,\cdots, ik_4) e^{i k_\mu x^\mu} \hat{g}(k) d^4k$$
I henceforth assume 
$$\left(f(\partial_{1},\cdots, \partial_{4}) g\right)(x) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2} \int_{\mathbb R^4} f(ik_1,\cdots, ik_4) e^{i k_\mu x^\mu} \hat{g}(k) d^4k\:,\tag{2}$$
where $f$ is a polynomial or a more complicated function which can be suitably approximated by polynomials. This identity entails
$$e^{-ihx}\left(f(\partial_{1},\cdots, \partial_{4}) e^{ihx}g\right)(x) = \frac{e^{-ihx}}{(2\pi)^2} \int_{\mathbb R^4} f(ik_1,\cdots, ik_4) e^{i k_\mu x^\mu} \widehat{e^{ihx}g}(k) d^4k\:,$$
On the other hand 
$$\widehat{e^{ihx}g}(k) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2} \int_{\mathbb R^4} f(ik_1,\cdots, ik_4) e^{-i (k_\mu-h_\mu) x^\mu}  g(x)d^4x = \hat{g}(k-h)\:,$$
so that, using the translational invarience of the measure $d^4k$
$$e^{-ihx}\left(f(\partial_{1},\cdots, \partial_{4}) e^{ihx}g\right)(x) = 
\frac{e^{-ihx}}{(2\pi)^2} \int_{\mathbb R^4} f(ik_1,\cdots, ik_4) e^{i k_\mu x^\mu} \hat{g}(k-h) d^4k$$
$$=
\frac{e^{-ihx}}{(2\pi)^2} \int_{\mathbb R^4} f(i(k_1+h_1),\cdots, i(k_4+h_4))e^{i (k_\mu-h_\mu) x^\mu} \hat{g}(k) d^4k$$ $$ = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2} \int_{\mathbb R^4} f(i(k_1+h_1),\cdots, i(k_4+h_4)) e^{i k_\mu x^\mu} \hat{g}(k) d^4k$$
Comparing with (2), paying attention to the fact that $ih_k$ act as a multiplicative constant when $f$ is a polynomials and thus in general, so it is equivalent to $ih_k\partial_k^0 = ih_kI$ when acting on $g(x)$ and not $\hat{g}(k)$ we have 
$$e^{-ihx}\left(f(\partial_{1},\cdots, \partial_{4}) e^{ihx}g\right)(x)$$
$$= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2} \int_{\mathbb R^4} f(i(k_1+h_1),\cdots, i(k_4+h_4)) e^{i k_\mu x^\mu} \hat{g}(k) d^4k$$
$$\left(f(\partial_{1}+ ih_1,\cdots, \partial_{4}+ih_4) g\right)(x)\:.$$
Since $g$ is generic,
$$e^{-ihx}f(\partial_{1},\cdots, \partial_{4}) e^{ihx} = f(\partial_{1}+ ih_1I,\cdots, \partial_{4}+ih_4I) \:.$$

Answer (score 1):

**PART 1 :**  Taylor Expansion ( see  @Prahar comment ).

In the following :

$$
\mathbf{x}=x^{\mu},  \quad  \mathbf{k}=k_{\mu},  \quad  \partial_{\mu}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}} , \quad  \mu=0,1,2,3
\tag{1-01}
$$

$$
\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}=k_{\mu}x^{\mu}=k^{\mu}x_{\mu}, \quad  \text{Einstein's convention on}\: \mu
\tag{1-02}
$$

Suppose now that the function $\:f\left(z\right)\:$ could be expanded in Taylor series, see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series.

$$
f\left(z\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{n=\infty}\dfrac{f^{\left(n\right)}\left(0\right)}{n!}\:z^{n}
\tag{1-03}
$$

so

$$
e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}} f\left(z\right)e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}} =\sum_{n=0}^{n=\infty}\dfrac{f^{\left(n\right)}\left(0\right)}{n!}\:e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}z^{n}e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}
\tag{1-04}
$$

For $z=\partial_{\mu}$ equation (1-04) gives

$$
e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}} f\left(\partial_{\mu}\right)e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}} =\sum_{n=0}^{n=\infty}\dfrac{f^{\left(n\right)}\left(0\right)}{n!}\:e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\partial_{\mu}^{\left(n\right)}e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}
\tag{1-05}
$$

In **PART 2**  we prove by induction the following equation :

$$
\bbox[#FFFF88,12px]{e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\partial_{\mu}^{\left(n\right)}e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}=\left( \partial_{\mu} + ik_{\mu}\right)^{n}}
\tag{1-06}
$$

so from (1-05)

$$
e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}} f\left(\partial_{\mu}\right)e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}} =\sum_{n=0}^{n=\infty}\dfrac{f^{\left(n\right)}\left(0\right)}{n!}\:\left( \partial_{\mu} + ik_{\mu}\right)^{n}=f\left( \partial_{\mu} + ik_{\mu}\right)
\tag{1-07}
$$
QED.

---

**PART 2 :**  Proof  by induction of equation (1-06) : $\:e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\partial_{\mu}^{\left(n\right)}e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}=\left( \partial_{\mu} + ik_{\mu}\right)^{n}$

Let a function $\:g\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\:$  infinitely differentiable. Then

(1). For $\:n=1\:$

\begin{align}
\left[e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\:\partial_{\mu}\:e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\right]\:g\left(\mathbf{x}\right) & =e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\:\partial_{\mu}\:\left[e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\:g\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\right]\\
& =e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\:\left[e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\:\partial_{\mu}\:g\left(\mathbf{x}\right)+ik_{\mu}e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}g\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\right]
\tag{2-01}\\
& = \left( \partial_{\mu}+ ik_{\mu} \right)g\left(\mathbf{x}\right) 
\end{align}
so
$$
e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\:\partial_{\mu}\:e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}= \left( \partial_{\mu}+ ik_{\mu} \right)
\tag{2-02}
$$

(2) Suppose that for a positive integer  $\:n\:$

$$
e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\partial_{\mu}^{\left(n\right)}e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}=\left( \partial_{\mu} + ik_{\mu}\right)^{n}
\tag{2-03}
$$

then

(3) for $\:n+1\:$ we have

\begin{align}
\left[e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\:\partial_{\mu}^{(n+1)}\:e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\right]\:g\left(\mathbf{x}\right) & = e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\:\partial_{\mu}^{(n)}\left(\partial_{\mu}\left[ e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\:g\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\right] \right)  \\
& = e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\:\partial_{\mu}^{(n)}\left[ e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\partial_{\mu}g\left(\mathbf{x}\right)+ik_{\mu}e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}g\left(\mathbf{x}\right) \right]\\
& =\underbrace{\left[e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\:\partial_{\mu}^{(n)}\:e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\right]}_{\left( \partial_{\mu} + ik_{\mu}\right)^{n}}\left( \partial_{\mu}+ ik_{\mu} \right)g\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\\
&= \left( \partial_{\mu}+ ik_{\mu} \right)^{n+1} g\left(\mathbf{x}\right)
\end{align}

so

$$
e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\:\partial_{\mu}^{(n+1)}\:e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}=\left( \partial_{\mu}+ ik_{\mu} \right)^{n+1} 
\tag{2-04}
$$

proving finally (1-06)

$$
\bbox[#FFFF88,12px]{e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\partial_{\mu}^{\left(n\right)}e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}=\left( \partial_{\mu} + ik_{\mu}\right)^{n}}
\tag{1-06}
$$